# How to use =VLOOKUP function in two Text column (like English to Bengali Dictionary)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unicode-string

Hello I want to use 2nd Column value based on 1st column value, and I have a table like below:
[image: examplecolumns]

I'm tried to use this formula in a cell:`=VLOOKUP(A2, A2:A5, 2, TRUE)` and got the value "**#REF!**"

How could i get the B column value in a cell based on column A's value? 
I want to update a column in others sheet based on these value, thats why I need this vlookup function to work for text value.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2, $A$2:$B$5, 2, TRUE)`  You need to specify the whole lookup table, not just the first column. And it's a good idea to make the table reference absolute so it won't change if you fill the formula down/across.  Even better, use a named range for the lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, A2:B5, 2, TRUE)
```

Change the `TRUE` to `FALSE` to find the exact matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, A2:B5, 2, TRUE)
```

The rang you set in your example contains only the first column

Answer (score 0):

Please Note that when using `VLOOKUP` formula, input range (`A2:A5` for above) should involve all columns, and starting with lookup-value columns.

Here I suggest you `LOOKUP` function and using `Table` capabilities, as below: (When your dictionary extends an columns grow up, `Table` addressing contains automatically.

(Please note that you have a Table range, which name is shown in `Design` tab, `Properties` group. (Here I assumed it's name is `Table1`)

(I):

```
=LOOKUP(A2,Table1[English],Table1[Bengali])
```

(II):

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(A2,Table1[English],0),2)
```

(III): (Approximately match)

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Table1,2,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

=VLOOKUP(A2,A2:B5,2,TRUE)